# iPhone base64 corrupted when posted to php script

Tags: php, iphone, ios, uiimageview, base64

In my app the user crops there picture i encode it to a base64 string and send it to my php script.I am using the NSData+base64 class However, when the app goes to retrieve the string again to convert back into a picture  I get this error:

```
Jan  8 14:21:33 Vessel.local Topic[11039] <Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Corrupt JPEG data:214        extraneous bytes before marker 0x68  Jan  8 14:21:33 Vessel.local Topic[11039] <Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Unsupported marker type 0x68
```

Here is the code in which i send off the data:

```
 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.php"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&email=%@&quote=%@&pic=%@",user,password,email,quote,pic];
[request setHTTPBody:[param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request  delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Here is when i get it back in another view controller and attempt to turn it back into a image

```
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

homeData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:nil error:nil];

NSString *decodeString = [[homeData objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"profile_pic" ];
decodeString = [decodeString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
int returnNUM = [decodeString length];
NSLog(@"RETURN STRING=%d",returnNUM);
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:decodeString]];

profilepic = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 4, 120, 120)];
profilepic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(profilepic.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:profilepic.bounds cornerRadius:80.0] addClip];
[pic drawInRect:profilepic.bounds];
profilepic.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.view addSubview:profilepic];
 }
```

How can i prevent the image from being corrupted once i post it..or once i get it back how can i clean it or prevent the corruption thats happening! This is driving me nuts..a clear answer with some code would be highly appreciated.Thanks

This is the code that I use to convert the image into base64 before i send it.

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(crop, 1.0);
    NSString *baseString = [imageData base64EncodedString];
    int original =[baseString length];
    NSLog(@"orignal String=%d",original);
    [self register:username.text withPass:password.text withEmail:email.text withQuote:quote.text withPic:baseString];
```

Comment: On the PHP side of things, do a `var_dump(substr($pic_data, 0, 512))` and post the results.  Might give us a bit more to work with.

Comment: are you sure that the picture's not getting mangled while in transit in either direction?

Comment: @Marc B - thats what im thinking..i sent the image to server and instantly made it echo back to simulator and it was corrupted..so its getting corrupted on the php side or in transit..i logged it in xcode and counted the characters and compared it before i sent it and it was the came character count

Comment: since it's base64, just decode it in php and save it out to a normal file somewhere. if it's a transmission glitch, you'll get garbage somewhere in the middle of the picture. a client/server-side error will probably add the corruption at the start or end of the pic

Comment: ok ill try that..becuause i performed the encode/decode locally to check to see if it was working properly and it was..so it has to be on  the php side or in transit..my only question is..is the base64 encode class i use compatible with the base64 class that is built into php? I used NSDATA+BASE64 class on iPhone that alot of people use, secondly if i decode it in php what will it become? A random string? an image? what can i store it as?

Comment: I mean i thought the whole purpose of base64 encoding was to ensure that the data is not corrupted over a transit..i dont know how to send both UIImage data and NSStrings in the same post..thats why i converted it into a string to get past that

Comment: @KevinHagens: Can you show the code that converts the image into the base64 encoded string `pic`? And where do the images originate from?

Comment: The images originated from the photo library..i crop them and save them as image jpeg representation then convert them..but i will edit my answer and show how i convert the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing the "stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet" call? That would seem to me to remove characters that the encoded image probably needs...

*Edit to include example from some code I'm using which correctly embeds a couple images into a http form to be submitted to a php page.*

I use the following Category on NSMutableData...

The following goes inside NSMutableData+HTTP.h

```
@interface NSMutableData (HTTP)

-(void)appendFileAtPath:(NSString*)fullFilePath withFormKey:(NSString*)formKey withSuggestedFileName:(NSString*)suggestedFileName boundary:(NSData*)boundary;
-(void)appendKey:(NSString*)key value:(NSString*)value boundary:(NSData*)boundary;

@end
```

The following goes inside NSMutableData+HTTP.m

```
#import "NSMutableData+HTTP.h"

@implementation NSMutableData (HTTP)

//use for attaching a file to the http data to be posted
-(void)appendFileAtPath:(NSString*)fullFilePath withFormKey:(NSString*)formKey withSuggestedFileName:(NSString*)suggestedFileName boundary:(NSData*)boundary{

    [self appendData:boundary]; 

    [self appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", formKey, suggestedFileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [self appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [self appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullFilePath]];

    [self appendData:[@"Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [self appendData:boundary]; 
}

//use for attaching a key value pair to the http data to be posted
-(void)appendKey:(NSString*)key value:(NSString*)value boundary:(NSData*)boundary{    
    [self appendData:boundary]; 
    [self appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [self appendData:[value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [self appendData:boundary]; 
}

@end
```

Then in my code that creates an http form submission I do the following to attach a couple images and key-value pairs (via the category methods above) to the form... (Note: I have not included the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods that you'll need to implement if you want to track the progress of the form submission.)

```
NSString *boundaryString = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
NSData *boundaryData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundaryString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *phpReceiverURL = @"http://www.someurl.com/somephppage.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:30];
[theRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[theRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[theRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phpReceiverURL]];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 

[theRequest addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundaryString] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

//add some image files to the form
[body appendFileAtPath:[imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cat.jpg"] 
    withFormKey:@"cat"  
    withSuggestedFileName:@"received-cat.jpg"
    boundary:boundaryData
];

[body appendFileAtPath:[imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dog.jpg"] 
    withFormKey:@"dog"  
    withSuggestedFileName:@"received-dog.jpg"
    boundary:boundaryData
];

//add some key value pairs to the form
[body appendKey:@"testkeyone" value:@"testvalueone" boundary:boundaryData]; 
[body appendKey:@"testkeytwo" value:@"testvaluetwo" boundary:boundaryData]; 

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[theRequest setHTTPBody:body];

//create the connection
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Also note I haven't tested this outside of my app so I may have forgotten something (such as "imagePath" which I haven't defined in the example above - you'll have to specify a path for your images), but it should give you a good idea of how to attach some images to a form to be submitted to a php page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok i will remove it..but i had added that after the first time i got the error..i assumed that line spaces or endlines where added during transit..but i think it still wouldnt work after i remove that

Comment: Also, in the line where you set "NSString *param", is "pic" the image data? If so I think you need to get its NSData and encode that before you add it to the param string.

Comment: pic is the base64 encoding of the image..so once i send it in the request it is already a base64 string. What do you think i need to do?

Comment: I added an example of some code I use which may help you to construct a form submission containing files and key-value pairs - I use it to send images and data to a php page.